# Laravel: After playing around with Ajax all my buttons inside a form post to same url

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel-4

I have a problem. Was trying to implement ajax post in **laravel** and now all my buttons with **type submit post to the same route** even if they didn't have any functionality before. Also, I had a cancel button that redirected to previous screen also with type submit that now also post to the same route as all other buttons... If I change the type the button just doesn't work. Removing the script doesn't impact.

Anyone got any ideas on what's might be going on or how to fix this?

Comment: Can you give us the code your using, have a look here on how to make your question better: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was that the buttons never even worked in the first place, I mistakenly copy/pasted the wrong html... sry